# synchronize files with different extension in MacOS

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, osx, rm

After a photo shoot I have two folders: JPGs (files *.jpg) and RAWs (files *.CR2). Usually I take a look in the JPGs folder and delete those ones that I don't like.

What I want is to create a bash script to check:

```
 for file.cr2 in folder.getFiles
   if file.jpg is NOT in folder2.getfiles 
      delete file.cr2
```

I have seen some examples with rsync but with files with the same extension and I'm not very good at bash, so I can do it in C but I want to learn.

Comment: are you looking for guidance for a C program, or for a command-line / shell-script based solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for file in cr2files/*; do
   test=”jpgfiles/$(basename ${file:: -3})jpg”
   if [ ! –f “$test” ]; then
      echo “$file”
   fi
done
```

If it gets the results that you want, you can replace the line - echo “$file” - with - rm “$file” -. The line – test=”jpgfiles/$(basename ${file:: -3])jpg” – removes the path and extention from the file name and replaces them with “jpgfile/filename.jpg” . Remember to change the pathnames “cr2files” and “jpgfiles” to the correct ones. You can use variables if you like or pass the path names to your script in arguments.

Edit:

Your space in “Toshiba ser” was messing up basename. Here’s the solution:

```
#!/bin /bash
IFS=’’
for file in “$1”/*; do
   test=”$2/$(basename ${file:: -3})jpg”
   if [ ! –f “$test” ]; then
      rm “$file”
   fi
done
```

Call it like this  ./removephotos.sh “volumes/toshiba ser/raw” "volumes/toshiba ser/jpg”. Take note that there is nothing between the single quotes in IFS='' on line #2.

Comment: Hi, Thanks at first. Im doing this: for file in $1; do
        filename="$(basename {$file)"
        filename="$2/${filename%.*}.JPG"

but when I write something like "removephotos.sh "/volumes/toshiba ser/raw/*" "/volumes/toshiba ser/jpg" it doesn't take the files