# Delete RAW image files that have no JPG counterpart

Tags: shell-script, macintosh, images

I want to delete every RAW image file (Photo image) that has no JPG counterpart.

Here's my current workflow:

1. My camera creates a RAW and a JPG for every photo I take.
2. I review the JPG files, and delete the ones I don't want (Since JPGs load much faster)
3. I currently manually go thought the folder, selecting any RAW file (*.cr3 in my case) that doesn't have a JPG pair (Because I deleted the JPG in the review process).

Example of what the files look like before I review them:

IMG_001.JPG
IMG_001.CR3
IMG_002.JPG
IMG_002.CR3
IMG_003.JPG
IMG_003.CR3
IMG_004.JPG
IMG_004.CR3

Example of what files look like after I've reviewed them

IMG_001.JPG
IMG_001.CR3
IMG_002.CR3
IMG_003.JPG
IMG_003.CR3
IMG_004.CR3

Both IMG_002 and IMG_004 are missing a jpg counterpart, meaning I deleted that jpg counterpart, and now I want to delete the raw file.

I've tried to follow the advice [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310893/synchronize-files-with-different-extension-in-macos): and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/517773/delete-files-same-name-but-different-file-extension): but to no avail.

This is my code right now:

```
for files in RAW/* 
do 
test="JPG/$(basename ${files::9})JPG"
if [ ! -f "$test" ]
then echo "$files"
fi 
done
```

or, the slick one-line version:

```
for files in RAW/*; do if [ ! -f "JPG/$(basename ${files::9})JPG" ]; then echo "$files"; fi done
```

or, the other one liner:

```
For files in RAW/*; [ ! -f "JPG/$(basename ${files::9})JPG" ] && echo "JPG/$(basename ${files::9})JPG"
```

The code assumes the raw and jpg files are in separate folders, which is fine. having them in the same folder is slightly more convenient, though.

Basically, I want to know how to write this script. I'm using the terminal on Mac OSX 15 Catalina.

Answer (score 2):

Since the files are in the same directory, let's keep it simple.

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in *.CR3; do
    noext=${file%.CR3}
    [ -f "$noext.JPG" ] || rm -- "$file"
done
```

The script loops over all `.CR3` files in the current directory. It removes the extension from the filename with `noext=${file%.CR3}`. If the `.JPG` counterpart does not exist, the `.CR3` file is removed (`[ -f "$noext.JPG" ] || rm -- "$file`).

You may want to add an `echo` between `||` and `rm` to see if the operation is correct before actually executing the script.

Answer (score 0):

If your files are as you wrote, you can find all the files that you need by

```
\ls -1 *.JPG *.CR3 | cut -d. -f1 | uniq -c | sed '/\<2\>/d
s/^[^I]*\(.*\)/\1.CR3/'
```

and delete them.  The complete command will be

```
rm $(\ls -1 | cut -d. -f1 | uniq -c | sed '/\<2\>/d
s/^[^I]*\(.*\)/\1.CR3/')
```

Effectively, you are getting the base name of each file by `cut`, sending it through `uniq -c` to count, deleting all the files that have 2 instances, and removing 1 and adding the extension `CR3`.